# jQuery conditional logic with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many articles which have multiple categories. I have a checkbox for every category. When a checkbox is checked the articles with this category should be shown, otherwise should be hidden.

So far so good.

When I check category 1, but not category 2 all posts should be shown which have category 1. If they have category 2 too they should be shown anyway.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="cat1" id="checkbox1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="cat2" id="checkbox2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="cat3" id="checkbox3" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="cat4" id="checkbox4" checked />
```

I use jQuery to show and hide the posts

```
if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
    $("article.category1").show();
} else {
    $("article.category1").hide();
}

if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    $("article.category2").show();
} else {
    $("article.category2").hide();
}

if ($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')) {
    $("article.category3").show();
} else {
    $("article.category3").hide();
}

if ($('#checkbox4').is(':checked')) {
    $("article.category4").show();
} else {
    $("article.category4").hide();
}
```

I created a js fiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/oliverspies/t8qHT/1/

If you uncheck all, but check the first checkbox, no entries are shown - but all entries with the class cat1 should be shown - even if they have another category which is unchecked.
How can I do this without writing tens of IF statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixed code

You can create a selector based on the input's value.

```
$('#catselector').on("change", function() {
  $("article").hide();
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", this).each(function(){
    $("article." + this.value).show();
  });
});
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tU3kh/)

---

### Previous code

```
$('#catselector').on("change", function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]", this).each(function(){
    $("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, but still not works like i need it. if you uncheck the second checkbox, all articles are hidden. but all articles with cat1, cat3 and cat4 should still be shown (because these checkboxes are checked)

Comment: Yes, you did it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's [toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
  $("article.cat1").toggle();
});
$('#checkbox2').click(function() {
  $("article.cat2").toggle();
});
...
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SCGyY/

Comment: thanks for this, but still not works like i need it. if you uncheck the second checkbox, all articles are hidden. but all articles with cat1, cat3 and cat4 should still be shown (because these checkboxes are checked)

Answer (score 0):

you may use [jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)() method on your `article.cat` objects inside checkbox's click method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $("article.category" + this.id[this.id.length - 1]).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Target all checkboxes (or a class if you prefer that) and get the last character from the ID (the number) and use it in the selector for article, and toggle that article based on the checkbox being checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#catselector :checkbox').change(function ( e ) {
  // hide all
  $( 'article' ).hide();

  // then filter and show selected
  $( '#catselector :checked' ).each(function() {
      $( 'article.' + this.value ).show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8qHT/14/